# How to read rows with IDs in array with findAllByPk()

Tags: php, yii

I have a table that saves related posts IDs.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria -> select = 'content_2';
$criteria -> condition = 'content_1=:c';
$criteria -> limit = $count;
$criteria -> params = array(':c' => $id);
$posts_id = SiteContentRelated::model() -> findAll($criteria);

$ids = array();

foreach ($posts_id as $value) {
    $ids[] = intval($value['content_2']);
}

$posts = SiteContent::model()->findAllByPk($ids);

echo '<pre style="direction:ltr;">';
print_r(count($posts));
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

And result:

```
1
```

And I am sure about count of rows in table(3 row).
Where is my mistake?

Comment: What does `var_dump($ids)` say?

Comment: That's not right, it should be an array. Possibly `$posts_id` does not contain the rows you think it should. Enable DB query/param logging, check the log to see the actual generated query. `var_dump($value['content_2'], $value->attributes)` for each row inside `$posts_id`.

Comment: Off topic: @DCoder, Can u please tell me How to Enable DB query/param logging?, thanks

Comment: @DCoder I checked this: `foreach ($posts_ids as $value) { echo $value['content_2'] . ',';}die();` And result: `220,315,212,256,316,211,213,200`

Comment: @LoverOfEvening: https://gist.github.com/4420192

Comment: @chalist: what are the primary keys of the rows you have in the `SiteContent` table? Why do you even have 8 different IDs when you say this table only contains 3 rows? Are you not enforcing data integrity?

Comment: @DCoder No dude, I added again and test it. Primery key is id

Answer (score 0):

As we dont know your dataset you should try debugging this first:

Compare :

```
count(SiteContent::model()->findAll())
```

and

```
count(SiteContent::model()->findAllByPk($ids))
```

If the results are not the same, your query is not what you want it to do. If they are both uncorrect, you dont have the right dataset.

On a second note, you should use var_dump instead of print_r for debugging. Print_r will show a Boolean as 1 or 0, instead of their real value